# Get Azure Web/Function App authentication configuration using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to get azure function and webapp authentication settings using powershell, I'm using the latest az modules (5.1). I can't see a way of getting this information, if I use `Get-AzFunctionApp` I can't see any authentication settings being returned unless I'm missing something.

Azure CLI can recover this using `az webapp auth show` but I was hoping to do this natively if possible.

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the powershell cmdlet [Invoke-AzResourceAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/invoke-azresourceaction?view=azps-5.1.0).

The example code:

```
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "your resource group name" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ResourceName "your webapp name or function app name/authsettings" -Action list -Force
```

**Note**:

for `-ResourceName`, if your `webapp name` or `function app name` is `mywebapp`, then you should specify it like this: `-ResourceName "mywebapp/authsettings"`.

for `-ResourceType`, it's always `"Microsoft.Web/sites/config"` for both webapp or functionapp.

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve what you need using the following:

```
Get-AzFunctionApp -name "testFunction00001" -resourcegroupname "resourceGroup00001" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty {A} | fl
```

Substitute {A} with one of the following:

- ApplicationSettings
- SiteConfig
- Config

Comment: As far as I can see Get-AzFunctionApp doesn't return these properties.

Comment: Is there any reason why you specifically need to use PowerShell? Azure CLI and PowerShell will work in tandem (mix-and-match) but I - given the option - would choose CLI over PowerShell simply because it works across multiple platforms.

Comment: it was more to do with not having to shell out and deal with authenticating the cli when this is used in automation